# What is the minimum of two independent variables?

Tags: probability, random-variable

I am having trouble to understand the min {X,Y} where X and Y are independent random variables.

From the online source, it says that  min{X,Y} < x if and only if X>x, Y>y.

First of all, what exactly do you mean by the  term "minimum " of the two random variables? Does it refer to the domains that X and Y can take, and you the minimum is the smallest value in that domain or what?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos  If **both** $X$ and $Y$ exceed the fixed number $z$, _how_ is it possible that $Z$, the **minimum** of $X$ and $Y$ is **smaller** than $z$? Won't the minimum _also_ exceed $z$? Isn't the correct result that $P\{Z > z\}$ if and only is _both_ $X$ and $Y$ exceed $z$?

Comment: Alecos: $P(\min\{X,Y\}\leq t)=1-P(\min\{X,Y\}>t)=1-P(X>t,Y>t)$.

Comment: @ZEn Thanks, I fell victim to the "notational mirror" effect.

Answer (score 3):

> what exactly do you mean by the term "minimum " of the two random variables?

It's a new random variable, which is equal to whichever of the two random variables is smaller.

For example, consider an experiment of repeatedly rolling two dice (say a black one and a red one) and at each roll recording whichever of the two has the smaller value.

If the value of the black die is $X$ and of the red die is $Y$ and we let $Z=\min(X,Y)$ then $Z$ is just the smaller of the pair each time we roll both.

(Independence would come in when computing the joint probability of $(X,Y)$.)